# How to find output for this?

Tags: c

What that x-- -y means here ?

[image]

(Gshsgshshzhhshshdjhzhzghhshsgxhgsgzhhzhzhshdhs )this is all rubbish I did because it was not accepting my question

Comment: Please write out your question properly. You should give a reasonable description to post. 
if you question is to get the value of x-- -y, then it can be achieved by 
z = (x--) - y;

Comment: it means nothing, x is not defined here

Comment: This was all I found in my book. I've added image.That might help.

Comment: @Shivam Tehanguria  x-- -y is the same as x --- y. :)

Answer (score 0):

`x-- -y`means "decrement x with 1 and subtract y from it".

Your program is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n = 4, y = 3, z;
    z = n-- - y;
    printf("\n%d%d%d", n, y, z);

}
```

The output is

```
331
```

z is 1 at the output because `n--` equals 4 and y equals 3, therefore z=n-- -y=1.